# Question about replacement and plot

Tags: replacement

I want to plug a value into the following solution which I defined.

```
    sol1=((1 + (3*θ)/2 - (1/2)*Sqrt[9*θ^2 + (2/3)*θ*(-1 + 18*θ) + (θ^2*(-23 - 252*θ + 324*θ^2))/(3*(73*θ^3 - 702*θ^4 + 6804*θ^5 - 5832*θ^6 + 54*Sqrt[6]*Sqrt[θ^6 + 17*θ^7 + 306*θ^8 - 324*θ^9])^(1/3)) + 
       (1/3)*(73*θ^3 - 702*θ^4 + 6804*θ^5 - 5832*θ^6 + 54*Sqrt[6]*Sqrt[θ^6 + 17*θ^7 + 306*θ^8 - 324*θ^9])^(1/3)] + (1/2)*Sqrt[18*θ^2 + (4/3)*θ*(-1 + 18*θ) - (θ^2*(-23 - 252*θ + 324*θ^2))/
        (3*(73*θ^3 - 702*θ^4 + 6804*θ^5 - 5832*θ^6 + 54*Sqrt[6]*Sqrt[θ^6 + 17*θ^7 + 306*θ^8 - 324*θ^9])^(1/3)) - (1/3)*(73*θ^3 - 702*θ^4 + 6804*θ^5 - 5832*θ^6 + 54*Sqrt[6]*Sqrt[θ^6 + 17*θ^7 + 306*θ^8 - 324*θ^9])^(1/3) + 
       (-96*θ^2 - 216*θ^3 - 24*θ^2*(-1 + 18*θ))/(4*Sqrt[9*θ^2 + (2/3)*θ*(-1 + 18*θ) + (θ^2*(-23 - 252*θ + 324*θ^2))/(3*(73*θ^3 - 702*θ^4 + 6804*θ^5 - 5832*θ^6 + 54*Sqrt[6]*Sqrt[θ^6 + 17*θ^7 + 306*θ^8 - 324*θ^9])^(1/3)) + 
           (1/3)*(73*θ^3 - 702*θ^4 + 6804*θ^5 - 5832*θ^6 + 54*Sqrt[6]*Sqrt[θ^6 + 17*θ^7 + 306*θ^8 - 324*θ^9])^(1/3)])])*(-((3*θ)/2) + (1/2)*Sqrt[9*θ^2 + (2/3)*θ*(-1 + 18*θ) + (θ^2*(-23 - 252*θ + 324*θ^2))/
  (3*(73*θ^3 - 702*θ^4 + 6804*θ^5 - 5832*θ^6 + 54*Sqrt[6]*Sqrt[θ^6 + 17*θ^7 + 306*θ^8 - 324*θ^9])^(1/3)) + (1/3)*(73*θ^3 - 702*θ^4 + 6804*θ^5 - 5832*θ^6 + 54*Sqrt[6]*Sqrt[θ^6 + 17*θ^7 + 306*θ^8 - 324*θ^9])^(1/3)] - 
    (1/2)*Sqrt[18*θ^2 + (4/3)*θ*(-1 + 18*θ) - (θ^2*(-23 - 252*θ + 324*θ^2))/(3*(73*θ^3 - 702*θ^4 + 6804*θ^5 - 5832*θ^6 + 54*Sqrt[6]*Sqrt[θ^6 + 17*θ^7 + 306*θ^8 - 324*θ^9])^(1/3)) - 
       (1/3)*(73*θ^3 - 702*θ^4 + 6804*θ^5 - 5832*θ^6 + 54*Sqrt[6]*Sqrt[θ^6 + 17*θ^7 + 306*θ^8 - 324*θ^9])^(1/3) + (-96*θ^2 - 216*θ^3 - 24*θ^2*(-1 + 18*θ))/(4*Sqrt[9*θ^2 + (2/3)*θ*(-1 + 18*θ) + (θ^2*(-23 - 252*θ + 324*θ^2))/
            (3*(73*θ^3 - 702*θ^4 + 6804*θ^5 - 5832*θ^6 + 54*Sqrt[6]*Sqrt[θ^6 + 17*θ^7 + 306*θ^8 - 324*θ^9])^(1/3)) + (1/3)*(73*θ^3 - 702*θ^4 + 6804*θ^5 - 5832*θ^6 + 54*Sqrt[6]*Sqrt[θ^6 + 17*θ^7 + 306*θ^8 - 324*θ^9])^(1/3)])] + 
    Sqrt[8*θ*(-((3*θ)/2) + (1/2)*Sqrt[9*θ^2 + (2/3)*θ*(-1 + 18*θ) + (θ^2*(-23 - 252*θ + 324*θ^2))/(3*(73*θ^3 - 702*θ^4 + 6804*θ^5 - 5832*θ^6 + 54*Sqrt[6]*Sqrt[θ^6 + 17*θ^7 + 306*θ^8 - 324*θ^9])^(1/3)) + 
           (1/3)*(73*θ^3 - 702*θ^4 + 6804*θ^5 - 5832*θ^6 + 54*Sqrt[6]*Sqrt[θ^6 + 17*θ^7 + 306*θ^8 - 324*θ^9])^(1/3)] - (1/2)*Sqrt[18*θ^2 + (4/3)*θ*(-1 + 18*θ) - (θ^2*(-23 - 252*θ + 324*θ^2))/(3*(73*θ^3 - 702*θ^4 + 6804*θ^5 - 5832*θ^6 + 54*Sqrt[6]*
                Sqrt[θ^6 + 17*θ^7 + 306*θ^8 - 324*θ^9])^(1/3)) - (1/3)*(73*θ^3 - 702*θ^4 + 6804*θ^5 - 5832*θ^6 + 54*Sqrt[6]*Sqrt[θ^6 + 17*θ^7 + 306*θ^8 - 324*θ^9])^(1/3) + (-96*θ^2 - 216*θ^3 - 24*θ^2*(-1 + 18*θ))/
            (4*Sqrt[9*θ^2 + (2/3)*θ*(-1 + 18*θ) + (θ^2*(-23 - 252*θ + 324*θ^2))/(3*(73*θ^3 - 702*θ^4 + 6804*θ^5 - 5832*θ^6 + 54*Sqrt[6]*Sqrt[θ^6 + 17*θ^7 + 306*θ^8 - 324*θ^9])^(1/3)) + (1/3)*(73*θ^3 - 702*θ^4 + 6804*θ^5 - 5832*θ^6 + 
                  54*Sqrt[6]*Sqrt[θ^6 + 17*θ^7 + 306*θ^8 - 324*θ^9])^(1/3)])]) + (-((3*θ)/2) + (1/2)*Sqrt[9*θ^2 + (2/3)*θ*(-1 + 18*θ) + (θ^2*(-23 - 252*θ + 324*θ^2))/(3*(73*θ^3 - 702*θ^4 + 6804*θ^5 - 5832*θ^6 + 54*Sqrt[6]*
                Sqrt[θ^6 + 17*θ^7 + 306*θ^8 - 324*θ^9])^(1/3)) + (1/3)*(73*θ^3 - 702*θ^4 + 6804*θ^5 - 5832*θ^6 + 54*Sqrt[6]*Sqrt[θ^6 + 17*θ^7 + 306*θ^8 - 324*θ^9])^(1/3)] - 
        (1/2)*Sqrt[18*θ^2 + (4/3)*θ*(-1 + 18*θ) - (θ^2*(-23 - 252*θ + 324*θ^2))/(3*(73*θ^3 - 702*θ^4 + 6804*θ^5 - 5832*θ^6 + 54*Sqrt[6]*Sqrt[θ^6 + 17*θ^7 + 306*θ^8 - 324*θ^9])^(1/3)) - (1/3)*(73*θ^3 - 702*θ^4 + 6804*θ^5 - 5832*θ^6 + 
              54*Sqrt[6]*Sqrt[θ^6 + 17*θ^7 + 306*θ^8 - 324*θ^9])^(1/3) + (-96*θ^2 - 216*θ^3 - 24*θ^2*(-1 + 18*θ))/(4*Sqrt[9*θ^2 + (2/3)*θ*(-1 + 18*θ) + (θ^2*(-23 - 252*θ + 324*θ^2))/(3*(73*θ^3 - 702*θ^4 + 6804*θ^5 - 5832*θ^6 + 
                   54*Sqrt[6]*Sqrt[θ^6 + 17*θ^7 + 306*θ^8 - 324*θ^9])^(1/3)) + (1/3)*(73*θ^3 - 702*θ^4 + 6804*θ^5 - 5832*θ^6 + 54*Sqrt[6]*Sqrt[θ^6 + 17*θ^7 + 306*θ^8 - 324*θ^9])^(1/3)])])^2]))/
  (θ/2 + (1/2)*Sqrt[9*θ^2 + (2/3)*θ*(-1 + 18*θ) + (θ^2*(-23 - 252*θ + 324*θ^2))/(3*(73*θ^3 - 702*θ^4 + 6804*θ^5 - 5832*θ^6 + 54*Sqrt[6]*Sqrt[θ^6 + 17*θ^7 + 306*θ^8 - 324*θ^9])^(1/3)) + 
      (1/3)*(73*θ^3 - 702*θ^4 + 6804*θ^5 - 5832*θ^6 + 54*Sqrt[6]*Sqrt[θ^6 + 17*θ^7 + 306*θ^8 - 324*θ^9])^(1/3)] - (1/2)*Sqrt[18*θ^2 + (4/3)*θ*(-1 + 18*θ) - (θ^2*(-23 - 252*θ + 324*θ^2))/
       (3*(73*θ^3 - 702*θ^4 + 6804*θ^5 - 5832*θ^6 + 54*Sqrt[6]*Sqrt[θ^6 + 17*θ^7 + 306*θ^8 - 324*θ^9])^(1/3)) - (1/3)*(73*θ^3 - 702*θ^4 + 6804*θ^5 - 5832*θ^6 + 54*Sqrt[6]*Sqrt[θ^6 + 17*θ^7 + 306*θ^8 - 324*θ^9])^(1/3) + 
      (-96*θ^2 - 216*θ^3 - 24*θ^2*(-1 + 18*θ))/(4*Sqrt[9*θ^2 + (2/3)*θ*(-1 + 18*θ) + (θ^2*(-23 - 252*θ + 324*θ^2))/(3*(73*θ^3 - 702*θ^4 + 6804*θ^5 - 5832*θ^6 + 54*Sqrt[6]*Sqrt[θ^6 + 17*θ^7 + 306*θ^8 - 324*θ^9])^(1/3)) + 
          (1/3)*(73*θ^3 - 702*θ^4 + 6804*θ^5 - 5832*θ^6 + 54*Sqrt[6]*Sqrt[θ^6 + 17*θ^7 + 306*θ^8 - 324*θ^9])^(1/3)])] + Sqrt[8*θ*(-((3*θ)/2) + (1/2)*Sqrt[9*θ^2 + (2/3)*θ*(-1 + 18*θ) + (θ^2*(-23 - 252*θ + 324*θ^2))/
           (3*(73*θ^3 - 702*θ^4 + 6804*θ^5 - 5832*θ^6 + 54*Sqrt[6]*Sqrt[θ^6 + 17*θ^7 + 306*θ^8 - 324*θ^9])^(1/3)) + (1/3)*(73*θ^3 - 702*θ^4 + 6804*θ^5 - 5832*θ^6 + 54*Sqrt[6]*Sqrt[θ^6 + 17*θ^7 + 306*θ^8 - 324*θ^9])^(1/3)] - 
       (1/2)*Sqrt[18*θ^2 + (4/3)*θ*(-1 + 18*θ) - (θ^2*(-23 - 252*θ + 324*θ^2))/(3*(73*θ^3 - 702*θ^4 + 6804*θ^5 - 5832*θ^6 + 54*Sqrt[6]*Sqrt[θ^6 + 17*θ^7 + 306*θ^8 - 324*θ^9])^(1/3)) - (1/3)*(73*θ^3 - 702*θ^4 + 6804*θ^5 - 5832*θ^6 + 
             54*Sqrt[6]*Sqrt[θ^6 + 17*θ^7 + 306*θ^8 - 324*θ^9])^(1/3) + (-96*θ^2 - 216*θ^3 - 24*θ^2*(-1 + 18*θ))/(4*Sqrt[9*θ^2 + (2/3)*θ*(-1 + 18*θ) + (θ^2*(-23 - 252*θ + 324*θ^2))/(3*(73*θ^3 - 702*θ^4 + 6804*θ^5 - 5832*θ^6 + 
                  54*Sqrt[6]*Sqrt[θ^6 + 17*θ^7 + 306*θ^8 - 324*θ^9])^(1/3)) + (1/3)*(73*θ^3 - 702*θ^4 + 6804*θ^5 - 5832*θ^6 + 54*Sqrt[6]*Sqrt[θ^6 + 17*θ^7 + 306*θ^8 - 324*θ^9])^(1/3)])]) + 
     (-((3*θ)/2) + (1/2)*Sqrt[9*θ^2 + (2/3)*θ*(-1 + 18*θ) + (θ^2*(-23 - 252*θ + 324*θ^2))/(3*(73*θ^3 - 702*θ^4 + 6804*θ^5 - 5832*θ^6 + 54*Sqrt[6]*Sqrt[θ^6 + 17*θ^7 + 306*θ^8 - 324*θ^9])^(1/3)) + 
          (1/3)*(73*θ^3 - 702*θ^4 + 6804*θ^5 - 5832*θ^6 + 54*Sqrt[6]*Sqrt[θ^6 + 17*θ^7 + 306*θ^8 - 324*θ^9])^(1/3)] - (1/2)*Sqrt[18*θ^2 + (4/3)*θ*(-1 + 18*θ) - (θ^2*(-23 - 252*θ + 324*θ^2))/(3*(73*θ^3 - 702*θ^4 + 6804*θ^5 - 5832*θ^6 + 
              54*Sqrt[6]*Sqrt[θ^6 + 17*θ^7 + 306*θ^8 - 324*θ^9])^(1/3)) - (1/3)*(73*θ^3 - 702*θ^4 + 6804*θ^5 - 5832*θ^6 + 54*Sqrt[6]*Sqrt[θ^6 + 17*θ^7 + 306*θ^8 - 324*θ^9])^(1/3) + (-96*θ^2 - 216*θ^3 - 24*θ^2*(-1 + 18*θ))/
           (4*Sqrt[9*θ^2 + (2/3)*θ*(-1 + 18*θ) + (θ^2*(-23 - 252*θ + 324*θ^2))/(3*(73*θ^3 - 702*θ^4 + 6804*θ^5 - 5832*θ^6 + 54*Sqrt[6]*Sqrt[θ^6 + 17*θ^7 + 306*θ^8 - 324*θ^9])^(1/3)) + (1/3)*(73*θ^3 - 702*θ^4 + 6804*θ^5 - 5832*θ^6 + 
                 54*Sqrt[6]*Sqrt[θ^6 + 17*θ^7 + 306*θ^8 - 324*θ^9])^(1/3)])])^2])
```

which looks complicate. Since the solution is only function of theta, I plug 1 into theta and get zero from the following code.

```
sol1 /. θ -> 1
```

However, if I plot the solution, it gives not zero when theta=1 from

```
Plot[sol1, {θ, 1, 10}]
```

Does anybody know why these two values are different?

Answer (score 1):

Use high values for the option settings for the options `MaxRecursion`, `PlotPoints` and `WorkingPrecision`:

```
Plot[sol1, {θ, 1, 10}, PlotRange -> {0, .4}, MaxRecursion -> 6,
  PlotPoints -> 200, WorkingPrecision -> 100]
```

[image]